# MATLAB -> struct.field(1:end).field?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way that I get all the structure subsubfield values of a subfield in one line ? Something like this :

```
struct.field(1:end).field
```

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question aright, you want to collect all the fields of the second-level structure, with the name 'field', into a single output array. It doesn't quite meet your request for a one-liner, but you can do it like this:

```
a.field1.a = 1;
a.field1.b = 2;
a.field2.a = 3;
a.field2.b = 4;

result = [];
for x = fieldnames(a)'
     result = horzcat(result, a.(x{:}).a);
end
```

The ending value of `result` is `[1 3]`

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Structure Example

```
aStruct.subField = struct('subSubField', {1;2;3;4})
```

So that

```
aStruct.subField(1).subSubField == 1
aStruct.subField(1).subSubField == 2
```

Etc. Then the values of the leaf nodes can be obtained via a one-liner as

```
valueLeafs = [aStruct.subField.subSubField];
```

Which can be checked via `assert(all(valueLeafs == [1,2,3,4]))`.

#### Non-Scalar Structure Example

The above one-liner also works when the leaf node values are non-scalar such that they can be horizontally concatenated. For example

```
bStruct.subField = struct('subSubField', {[1,2];[3,4]})
valueLeafs_b     = [bStruct.subField.subSubField]; % works okay
cStruct.subField = struct('subSubField', {[1,2];[3;4]})
valueLeafs_c     = [cStruct.subField.subSubField]; % error: bad arg dims
```

#### Distinct Class Structure Example

The one-line solution given previously does not work whenever the leaf node values are different class since they cannot - in general, be concatenated. However, use of `arrayfun` and a *tricky* anonymous function typically provide the required indexing technique:

```
dStruct.subField = struct('subSubField', {[1;2];'myString'});
valueLeafs_d     = arrayfun(@(x) x.subSubField, dStruct.subField, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: Apologize for digging up an old post but I found your answer very useful as I had a similar problem and a structure similar to your '**dStruct**' and I thought you might add another case to your answer.
specifically I had something like this:

`eStruct(1).subField = struct('subSubField', {[1;2];'myString'});`

`eStruct(1).subField = struct('subSubField', {[1;2];'myString'});`

Then you can retrieve your subfield as:

`valueLeafs_e     = arrayfun(@(x) x.subSubField, [eStruct.subField], 'UniformOutput', false)`